# Issue inserting timestamp value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, ado

There are some other questions where people have problems with timestamp being all zeros. I have checked them and this is not a duplicate.

I declare a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE  `my_db`.`my_table` (
  `time_stamp` timestamp NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar() NOT NULL,
  `text` text NOT NULL,
  `md5` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`time_stamp`)
) ;
```

I also have a second table which will have a timestamp as primary key and they should have the same value.

Coding in Delphi, I use `SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` which returns something like `'19/6/2010 4:56:17 AM'` which I then use in an INSERT statement. The INSERT succeeds, but the timestamp is all zeros.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the INSERT code:

```
  sqlCommand := 'INSERT INTO my_db.my_table(time_stamp, author, text, md5) VALUES ("' 
                   + timestamp + 
                    '", "mawg", ' +
                    '"Hello, world"' +
                    0 +
                    '");';
  Result := DoSQlCommandWithNoResultSet(sqlCommand, AdoConnection);
```

Insertion will be extremely low rate, one entry every few weeks or maybe months, so I am happy with timestamp as primary key. I am keeping "versions" of things, so timestamp makes sense to me.

I am begging to think that this is an ADO problem, although I would expect ADO to just "pass through". I don't see any other solution. In a console, the output is "correct", but when run through ADO in Delphi then it is wrong

Can I specify to MySQL how it ought to format its dates?

Comment: Let's see the code which does the insert.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you want to use timestamp field? Consider to use datatime type instead. And It's impossible to have '19/6/2010 4:56:17 AM' from CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel - please remember that I am a n00b and explain the pros & cons of datatime vs timestamp.

And, although you say "It's impossible to have '19/6/2010 4:56:17 AM' from CURRENT_TIMESTAMP". I just ran the code again and the Delphi debugger gave the value as `19/6/2010 9:01:35 AM`.    

  Xampp...

Comment: Being a noob, you can always refer to a manual page for the explanations.

Comment: lol, Col - I'm not that much of a n00b.  #1 RTFM  #2 google  #3  ask at stack overflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reviewing the MySQL documentation, it appears that if your `timestamp` value is incorrectly formatted, it would normally cause the timestamp to be `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'`.
In any case, you don't need to specify a timestamp value—that's the benefit of `TIMESTAMP` over `DATETIME`. And even if you did, you can simply set it to `NOW()` instead of running an unnecessary `SELECT` statement.

Edit:

Also, I know you said you thought this through, but have you considered daylight savings time? This could cause two records to have the same timestamp when the clock is set back during autumn.

Edit 2:

K, I don't know why I didn't catch this earlier, but that timestamp format you gave is incorrect. Try inserting a valid timestamp like `'2010/06/19 4:56:17'`. MySQL has pretty relaxed parsing of date & time values, but it always has to be year-month-date and hour-minute-seconds.

Edit 3:

Alright, there seems to be a little confusion over this, so I'm gonna post this quote from the MySQL 5.0 doc page on the [`DATETIME` format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html):

> For values specified as strings that include date part delimiters, it is not necessary to specify two digits for month or day values that are less than 10. '1979-6-9' is the same as '1979-06-09'. Similarly, for values specified as strings that include time part delimiters, it is not necessary to specify two digits for hour, minute, or second values that are less than 10. '1979-10-30 1:2:3' is the same as '1979-10-30 01:02:03'.

Comment: It should be `HH`, not `H`, so `2010/06/19 04:56:17` is correct.

Comment: Well, you're allowed to omit the preceding zero in single-digit months/dates/hours/minutes/seconds. Check the docs again (after the part about illegal dates being converted to 0000-00...). I think it's mainly the order of the date values that's screwing it up.

Comment: +! "fter reviewing the MySQL documentation, it appears that if your timestamp  value is incorrectly formatted"
    +1 "It should be HH, not H"   -  that's what I thought ... _*BUT*_ I got the value from `SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` - can it be a Delphi problem? I Don't see how - it just gets a string back.

Comment: I'm guessing it's a Delphi issue. Do you have a MySQL client or access to one? Because if you run the query: `SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;` it actually returns this: `2010-06-19 04:22:12`. And try it with just H:MM:SS. It should work without the 0 padding. Likewise, try the insert by leaving out `time_stamp` altogether. It should work as well.

Comment: @Lèse majesté I failed to find anything about omitting zeros in MySQL date-related docs, but ok, let it be (:

Comment: hudolejev, I apologize. I got confused between the link you posted and the page I was looking at. But I'll link to it in my answer =].

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [MySQL date functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html). They are very extensive and allow a high flexibility.

Besides all that, I would recommend re-thinking your table structure. A timestap as a primary key is not exactly what you want. When you have high traffic, it CAN happen, that the timestamp is the same. Also if you are saving 2 or more records in a row, the timestamp will be the same. Furthermore, your MD5 column is set to int(11). MD5 hashes use mixed characters, so i would rather go with varchar(32).

```
CREATE TABLE  `my_db`.`my_table` ( 
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `text` text NOT NULL,
  `md5` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ;
```

Comment: yes, I did have a look at them. But I have a problem, which is why I amm here :-/    

ANd, yes, I have though it though and a timestamp is exactly what I want. I need to capture a "version" and there is no other way to do it.

And, yes, timestamp can happen at the same time, but my application is threaded, with mutex, etc 

At least, I think I know what I am doing ;-)

btw, +1  Thanks for replying

Comment: @hudolejev - I really need "versions". The timestamp is the only possible (*) key to a first step index table which points to other more "normally indexed" tables.  (* I could use some very contrived thing as PK< but only if I jump through hoops. As a Use Case, timestamp is what makes sense for "versions")

Answer (score 1):

AFAIR `19/6/2010 4:56:17 AM` is not a valid date format for MySQL date types. You should convert it to `2010-06-19 04:56:14` (see [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html)).

Comment: +1 The strange thing is that I got that string from MySql itself with `SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.  Is there any function to "normalize" the timestamp?

Comment: Maybe `STR_TO_DATE()`? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: +1 but why should have to use `STR_TO_DATE()` ? I am just using the retune value of `NOW()`

Comment: Strange. MySQL function `NOW()` should return a time in valid format. If you are retrieving that value from query result with some Delphi function, I guess it is it who corrupts the time format. You could check that by printing the raw query result before parsing it.